# Any ideas on how to save location point to MySQL variable

Tags: android, mysql, json, geolocation, location

In my android app, I'm saving and retrieving data to MySQL db with the help of JSON, thus I can use String only. Any thoughts on how to convert my location to String, and save it to MySQL VARCHAR variable, and retrieve it from the db to convert into GPS location again?

Comment: can you post some code? it would be easier to assist you

Comment: Convert location double value to string then save in database and after read string from database convert it double again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them in a String variable and parse the lat & Long as

```
new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("lat string value"),Double.parseDouble("long string value")))
```